# asp.net MVC Serving Dynamic images not working on server (only local)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-2, devexpress

I am trying to get a DevExpress gauge Control to work in MVC. The actual tutorial lives here: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E2976.aspx. What it does it via an xml file cretate settings and build an image which is then stored in a memory stream in the controller and pushed out to an img tag that lives on a View. This img tags src attr is calling the Url.Action to call the action to Render the Gauge. The Code in the Controller looks like this

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1000, VaryByParam = "param")]
        public ActionResult RenderGauge(double param)
        {
            ASPxGaugeControl ctrl = new ASPxGaugeControl();
            param = param * 100;
            ctrl.RestoreLayoutFromXml(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/gauge.xml"));
            (ctrl.Gauges["myGauge"] as CircularGauge).Scales["myScale"].Value = (float)param;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            ctrl.ExportToImage(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

The View looks like this:

```
<div style="background: 1px solid Blue; width; 240px;">
<%  double data = Model.ListData[0].Percentage; %>
                    <img src='<%: Url.Action("RenderGauge", "GetDashBoard", new RouteValueDictionary(new { param = data })) %>'
                        alt="Gauge showing data" id="gaugeImg1" />

    </div>
```

Again, this all works on my local machine, but pukes on the server. The src attr seems to render fine:

```
<img src='/CINet/CorporateDashBoard/GetDashBoard/RenderGauge?param=0.7'
                        alt="Gauge showing data" id="gaugeImg1" />
```

I'd also like to add that this is IIS 7, MVC 2 and I have tried adding special handlers that I have found on the internet with no success:

```
<handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v11.2, Version=11.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="PNG Images" path="*.png" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
 </handlers>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the full path when page is rendered ? have you looked at the url in any html debug tool (firebug etc), may be there is an issue with image path.

Comment: What exactly does it puke on the server?

Comment: What happens when you type the url of the action directly in your browser's address bar: `http://yourserver/CINet/CorporateDashBoard/GetDashBoard/RenderGauge?param=0.7`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your questions, it was weird because it never puked and going directly there yielded the same results of the 'x' and alt text being displayed but no image. Turned out to be that the Gauge dll for DevExpress was not being copied locally on the server. Would have thought I would have gotten a complaining exception for that, but oh well. Hope this helps others